# adding javascript type animation to html isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to add the typing animation to my existing html document for a project i'm working on. I tried following multiple videos, and the animation works when made in its own html/css documents, but when using the same steps to add into my existing project, it doesn't work.

github repo used: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

I ended up cloning the files into a folder and adding type.js to a folder within the project. the location would be .\javascript\typed.js

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
                <ul id="sidemenu">
                    <li><a href="#header">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" onclick="closemenu()"></i>
                </ul>
                <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bars" onclick="openmenu()"></i>
            </nav>
            <div class="header-text-style">
                <p>im a<span id="animate"></span>
                </p>
                <h1>Hi, i'm <span>Elf</span><br> from the North Pole</h1>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

bottom, but in body:

```
<script src="javascript/typed.js"></script>
<script>
    var typed = new Typed('.animate', {
        strings: ["Coding", "Sleeping", "third word"],
        typeSpeed: 150,
        backSpeed: 150,
        loop: true
    })
</script>
```

```
.header-text-style p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: poppins;
    color: green;
    font-size: 4.5em;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(#fff , .5);
}
#animate{
    color: chartreuse;
}
```

Comment: First step to debugging: Check de console. Do you have any errors?

Comment: If I'm looking at the correct library, pretty sure `Typed('.animate', ` should be `Typed('#animate', ` - that first argument is the selector, and you want an id selector, not a class selector

Comment: You are referring an element with the class "animate" (`new Typed('.animate',{})`), but in HTML you have element with `id="animate"`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Tieson, you are using an id for the element you want to animate. The selector for ids is a `#` not a `.`.

Instead of cloning the files and using them locally, you can also use a CDN like CDNjs to serve the library (as seen in the jsfiddle).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.5/typed.min.js" integrity="sha512-1KbKusm/hAtkX5FScVR5G36wodIMnVd/aP04af06iyQTkD17szAMGNmxfNH+tEuFp3Og/P5G32L1qEC47CZbUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
var typed = new Typed('#animate', {
    strings: ["Coding", "Sleeping", "third word"],
    typeSpeed: 150,
    backSpeed: 150,
    loop: true
})
</script>
```

JsFiddle with the animation working: https://jsfiddle.net/1qwejn40/19/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I spent a good 2 hours for something as small as changing an id # to a class .